# Authentication with p12 key to google

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have `.p12` which is stored in a file key from my google bigquery database. Now what I need is just to execute some select from my terminal. When I run

```
gcloud init --console-only
```

the next step is that it asks me authentication key. Why? I just want to use my `.p12` key. How to authenticate with this key?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You have a service account, and want to authenticate using that key and talk to BigQuery from your terminal. Is that right?

Comment: @GrahamPolley Yes, exactly right

Answer (score 2):

You can auth to gcloud with a p12 as you would expect:

> gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE

Important:

> The key file can be .json (preferred) or .p12 (legacy) format. For
>   legacy .p12 files, a separate password might be required. This
>   password is displayed in the console when you create the key.

You can find more info on https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account